# How to get rid of GitLens+ Pro screen in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

I installed GitLens in VS Code. Then it asked if I wanted to try the GitLens+ features. I clicked "Yes". Now I am stuck at the welcome screen and can't get past it. Any ideas how to get rid of this annoying screen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when we install GitLens extension then all the GitLens features and buttons are added under the generic source control tab (Ctrl+shift+G). Even though GitLens creates a new tab of its own and it looks like all features and buttons are hiding behind the welcome screen. This is not the case and everything but the welcome screen is under the generic source control tab. Poor design choice indeed.

Comment: Poor design choice if they want you to use the free options. Good design choice if they want you to _think_ you have to pay to use even the free options, yet they remain able to boast about what a wide variety of free features they have. 8-)

Answer (score 21):

Hide GitLens+ Features from the Command Palette `GitLens+: Hide GitLens+ Features`

To restore from the Command Palette `GitLens+: Restore GitLens+ Features`

Comment: This is really the best answer as it removes the ads, yet still lets you use the free features like the line blame and hover tools.

Comment: Version 14.1.1: Command Palette `GitLens: Hide Pro Features`

Answer (score 20):

Uninstall gitlens extension. Productivity extensions shouldn't reduce productivity by putting up adds that can't easily be closed.

Comment: I use gitgraph is minimalist for what I need in vscode. Gitlense is just bloat. Btw I am here because I was trying a few including gitlense and is just too annoying with the trial stuff.

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Comment: Um, actually it is! Read the question and think about it. 8-)

Comment: This "answer" is more suited as a comment. Uninstalling maybe a fair answer, but only if an alternative app is provided. Otherwise, any problem I encounter with X app, can be answered with "Uninstall X". Which is not helpful. As annoyed as I am to have to search for this, GitLens gives 99% of what everyone needs for free and, as pointed out by a more recent answer, pro features in the UI can be turned off.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, but I was able to solve it by following the steps below.

1. Open the sidebar extension
2. Click the down arrow to the right of the uninstall
3. Install another version
4. Install 11.7.0
5. Reload

But there was no Gitlens in the sidebar
So next

6. "git lens: show welcome view" in the command palette
7. Select "git lenses layout" in "view" of "quick setup"

Gitlens is displayed in the sidebar

8. Then install the latest version

Gitlens is displayed in the sidebar

I hope it helps you even a little.

Comment: Shessh, I landed here by googling another issue of latest 12.2.2 not working well on workspaces and annoying with plus features/trials. *Going back to 11.7.0 fixed both things.* No doubt Kraken damned it.

Answer (score 4):

Go to VS Code command Pallete and select GitLens+: Sign out of Gitlens+

that should get you to the previous experience.

[image: How to sign out of Gitlens+ on VS Code]

you can also use the the VSCode Command Pallete to display the views you want, such as

[image: Show Stashes view]

I think I had the same issue on Windows (now I'm on my mac) so I went back to Windows, created a new account, and started the trial since logging off of my account on Windows didn't result in that scenario.

I couldn't reproduce it on Windows either.

I'm thinking that might be a glitch, I'm sure you already tried to close VSCode and open again, so, maybe try to sign out and sign in again.

If you want to remove the "home" view, use the elipses on the top right and untick it. Also, check if the other views are enabled.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the tips, especially regarding signing out of Gitlens+. As I couldn't figure out how to sign out. However, it didn't really help :-D . Even after signing out I am still stuck at the annoying welcome screen and can't really see any of the buttons

Comment: I think that with the new experience, the welcome is always there, signed in and off, but what I noticed on your screenshot was that the views were missing (commits, repositories, etc...) the "home" view is the main one and is always visible unless you hide it. If you need extra help, reach out...

Comment: @exan any luck there? I updated my answer with more information.

Answer (score 2):

#### Step 1. Uninstall `GitLens`

This avoids fiddling with settings to try to stop it being nag-ware.

#### Step 2. Install `Git Graph`

This has the nicest "railway-track" display of commits that I have come across, although the dev seems to be not responding to contact during 2022.

An alternative is `Git History`, which remains under active development, although its railway-track display is less compact and efficient.

Comment: Installing another plugin is not what's being asked here.

Comment: I agree, but it is what I ended up doing and I am very happy with the result. One of the wonderful things about Stack Overflow is that it opens us up to solution paths that we would not otherwise have considered. 8-)

Comment: I'd rather make this a comment then, not an answer.

Comment: Feel free to do so!

Comment: some interesting functionalities like git blame are absent of git graph